# Use of a "primitive" function in a contract

Tags: solidity, erc-721, erc165

A solidity amateur here. I have a deeper question. Let's say we have a IERC721 contract. And in the beginning of this contract we have the following code:

```
interface IERC721 is IERC165 {
/**
 * @dev Emitted when `tokenId` token is transferred from `from` to `to`.
 */
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed tokenId);

/**
 * @dev Emitted when `owner` enables `approved` to manage the `tokenId` token.
 */
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed approved, uint256 indexed tokenId);

/**
 * @dev Emitted when `owner` enables or disables (`approved`) `operator` to manage all of its assets.
 */
event ApprovalForAll(address indexed owner, address indexed operator, bool approved);

/**
 * @dev Returns the number of tokens in ``owner``'s account.
 */
function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256 balance);

/**
 * @dev Returns the owner of the `tokenId` token.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `tokenId` must exist.
 */
function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address owner);

/**
 * @dev Safely transfers `tokenId` token from `from` to `to`, checking first that contract recipients
 * are aware of the ERC721 protocol to prevent tokens from being forever locked.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `from` cannot be the zero address.
 * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
 * - `tokenId` token must exist and be owned by `from`.
 * - If the caller is not `from`, it must be have been allowed to move this token by either {approve} or {setApprovalForAll}.
 * - If `to` refers to a smart contract, it must implement {IERC721Receiver-onERC721Received}, which is called upon a safe transfer.
 *
 * Emits a {Transfer} event.
 */
function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external;

/**
 * @dev Transfers `tokenId` token from `from` to `to`.
 *
 * WARNING: Usage of this method is discouraged, use {safeTransferFrom} whenever possible.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `from` cannot be the zero address.
 * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
 * - `tokenId` token must be owned by `from`.
 * - If the caller is not `from`, it must be approved to move this token by either {approve} or {setApprovalForAll}.
 *
 * Emits a {Transfer} event.
 */
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external;

/**
 * @dev Gives permission to `to` to transfer `tokenId` token to another account.
 * The approval is cleared when the token is transferred.
 *
 * Only a single account can be approved at a time, so approving the zero address clears previous approvals.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - The caller must own the token or be an approved operator.
 * - `tokenId` must exist.
 *
 * Emits an {Approval} event.
 */
function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) external;

/**
 * @dev Returns the account approved for `tokenId` token.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `tokenId` must exist.
 */
function getApproved(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address operator);

/**
 * @dev Approve or remove `operator` as an operator for the caller.
 * Operators can call {transferFrom} or {safeTransferFrom} for any token owned by the caller.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - The `operator` cannot be the caller.
 *
 * Emits an {ApprovalForAll} event.
 */
function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool _approved) external;

/**
 * @dev Returns if the `operator` is allowed to manage all of the assets of `owner`.
 *
 * See {setApprovalForAll}
 */
function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) external view returns (bool);

/**
  * @dev Safely transfers `tokenId` token from `from` to `to`.
  *
  * Requirements:
  *
  * - `from` cannot be the zero address.
  * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
  * - `tokenId` token must exist and be owned by `from`.
  * - If the caller is not `from`, it must be approved to move this token by either {approve} or {setApprovalForAll}.
  * - If `to` refers to a smart contract, it must implement {IERC721Receiver-onERC721Received}, which is called upon a safe transfer.
  *
  * Emits a {Transfer} event.
  */
function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes calldata data) external;
}
```

I call this primitive functions(correct me if I am wrong)- functions that are defined in the scope of the IERC721 standard. Later this functions are defined in the ERC721:

```
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
        require(ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId) == from, "ERC721: transfer of token that is not own"); // internal owner
        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

        // Clear approvals from the previous owner
        _approve(address(0), tokenId);

        _holderTokens[from].remove(tokenId);
        _holderTokens[to].add(tokenId);

        _tokenOwners.set(tokenId, to);

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

And then the _transfer function is again used as some other function of the IERC721:

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual override {
        //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
       _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

In this case, I used the transfer as the example. Can only transferfrom be called, or can a more primitive function be preformed? In a broader sense lets say these are the functions that can be "used"(preformed?) on a contract:
[image]
Can any functions be called outside of this list?

Comment: Search up the difference between external/public and internal functions. `_transfer` is internal and can't be called externally. The functions that can be called are all the external/public ones.